# Getting size of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

I have an example as follows:

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct e{

    int *(array[2]); <---in my case this array is a [2][69]

}Example;
```

and then this if i have a function such as:

```
int funct(Example *e);
```

How can I get the size of the array?

I tried:

```
int size =(sizeof(e->array[0])/sizeof(int));
```

But it does not return value of 69.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.c-faq.com/, section 6.

Comment: How many times are you going to ask this again and again?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot because you cannot pass arrays to functions (or return them for that matter).  When you pass an array as an argument it decays to a pointer to the first element.  You will have to pass the size as well.

Think about it; if you could actually pass an *array* (not a pointer!  They're different animals.), why would all of those standard library functions take a pointer and the size?

Comment: Yes, array is diffent from pointer

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the size.. You cannot find the size without this..

Comment: ok, thanks. I used the function to calculate the size of array which was provided. Thanks for the replies!